# Syntax Error after installing python when attempting to use the pip command

Tags: python, django, pip

I am attempting to install python and Django. I am getting this error every time I attempt to install anything with pip. All I have done right now is

```
brew install python
```

Then, I used:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

After when doing the command below I get the sytanx error.

```
Stefanoss-MBP:javaTutor fetz$ python -m pip install Django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
```

Comment: Why are you using python `2.7`? `sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")` is Python 3.6 f-string formatting.

Comment: You seem to have somehow managed to install pip3 on Python 2. Try `python3 -m pip ...`

Comment: @PacketLoss I am just typing the commands that I placed above. Not changing anything else I am not sure of what to do. Uninstalling python and reinstalling it doesn't work. I need the latest version of python

Comment: @Selcuk this worked thanks

Comment: @Selcuk python3 is for version 3 in general so 3.8 included or just 3.0

Comment: Sorry is that a question or a statement? It depends on which version `brew` installed.